# How to display custom AVPlayer video layer in QT

Tags: ios, objective-c, qt, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm working on a custom QT component to create my own iOS player (as I need a modified version of it's default MediaPlayer for DRM).

So far I managed to create a simple component.

header file:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QQuickItem>

class CustomPlayer : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:

public:
    CustomPlayer(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    Q_INVOKABLE void play();
};
```

mm file:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#include <AVKit/AVKit.h>

#include "customplayer.h"


//===================================

CustomPlayer::CustomPlayer(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickItem(parent)
{
}

void CustomPlayer::play()
{
    AVPlayer *_player;
    AVURLAsset *_asset;
    AVPlayerItem *_playerItem;

    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];

    NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

    _asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:baseURL];

    _playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: _asset];

    [_player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];

    [_player play];
}
```

It's still a really rough version, but with this I can use CustomPlayer in my QML code. 
But what I'm struggling with is creating a layer for the video to render to.

I'm trying to understand how QT has it's MediaPlayer created by looking at the source code in [qtmultimedia](https://github.com/qt/qtmultimedia) but I'm having a hard time in understanding it.
How would one create an output for the player so it's displayed inside the CustomPlayer component?

Answer (score 0):

This is C++ code (the parent class is QQuickPaintedItem):

```
// header

class VideoViewport : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit VideoViewport(QQuickItem *parent = nullptr);

    void paint(QPainter *painter) override;
public slots:
    void updateImage(const QImage& frame);
private:
    QImage _currentImage;
};

// impementation in the *.cpp file
VideoViewport::VideoViewport(QQuickItem *parent):
    QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
}

void VideoViewport::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QSizeF _size = _currentImage.size();
    _size.scale(this->boundingRect().size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    QRectF output = QRectF(QPointF(0, 0), _size);
    output.moveCenter(boundingRect().center());
    painter->drawImage(output, _currentImage);
}

void VideoViewport::updateImage(const QImage &frame)
{
    _currentImage = frame;
    update();
}
```

In main.cpp

```
int main(...)
{
    //...
    qmlRegisterType<VideoViewport>("your.path.to.widgets", 1, 0 , "VideoViewport");
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll try to see how can I add that part into my component, as I originally wanted to do.

Comment: You need to make the inheritance of your CustomPlayer from QQuickPaintedItem, override the paint method and create a method for update a video's frame. From a gui you send path of a media source into some reader  where you form a frame image for the viewport

Comment: I can't change the inheritance of the CustomPlayer, I would loose all other properties, no?

Comment: Is it possible to use QVideoWidget for displaying the video?

Comment: @wtferror http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html

Comment: I did find that example, but the problem I'm having is how to actually implement that with AVPlayer for ios, as I'm new in that field and my knowledge is quite limited. I'll keep on trying to understand how this works.